# What exactly is the :method: notation supposed to do for ruby docs?

Tags: ruby, minitest

Minitest has a bunch of methods defined like so:

```
  ##
  # :method: must_equal
  # See MiniTest::Assertions#assert_equal

  ##
  # :method: must_include
  # See MiniTest::Assertions#assert_includes

  ##
  # :method: must_match
  # See MiniTest::Assertions#assert_match

  ##
  # :method: must_output
  # See MiniTest::Assertions#assert_output
```

These are defined in the `Object` module, so they're available on all objects. But why aren't they showing up in any docs? I've checked the docs generated by Yard on `rdoc.info`, and the ones generated by `rdoc` when I type `gem rdoc minitest`. They don't show up on either. How am I supposed to reference these if they don't show up anywhere? What is `:method:` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a way of documenting a method that doesn't get explicitly defined. There are occasions when you might want to add a note about a method that gets generated dynamically, for instance, or is loaded in from another module as is the case here.

Comment: I figured that, but why are the 2 main documentation generators not picking it up?